# Copy number to another intent/app textbox

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to copy a number (total sale) from my app to the credit card processing app that i am using (square). how could i do that? i am trying to use intents.

```
        chargeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View h) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,          textResult.getText().toString() );
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.squareup",
                    "com.squareup.ui.PaymentActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

i have searched all over and the only answer i am getting involves the secound app .getextras which i cant add to an app that's not mine. please provide code if possible.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the API documentation your following? Linky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to use square without installing [squareup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.squareup) on device

download helper library [here](https://github.com/square/android-api/downloads)

use code from [here](http://corner.squareup.com/android-api/javadoc/com/squareup/android/Square.html) to make your payment

Comment: i have an account with square and the is installed on my device. i will look up the docs you've attached thank you very much!!.

Comment: could you help me insert the code to take the amount from textResult and put into square?? thanks again

Comment: convert textResult.getText() to double(Double.parseDouble) then multiply it with 10, convert to int(casting (int)double) and pass result to this `.price(2, Currency.USD)` line(instead of 2)